# Creating a dictionary by looping over lists only produces last list's elements

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to construct a dictionary (=results), which loops over a list of names (=namelist, strings)and gives me the amount nameA (name B an so forth) are mentioned in a list with several articles (=articles, strings).

My code is the following:

```
import csv
results={}

for elements in namelist:
    for article in articles:
        list_namecounts = len(re.findall(element,article))
        results[article]=[element, list_namecounts]
```

However, instead of returning a dictionary with all namecounts for each element in namelist, it only produces a dictionary including the last element, so the last name.

Anyone having a suggestion how to solve this in my code?

Comment: initialize `results={}` after 1st loop

Comment: Thanks @akashkarothiya - how would initialising after the 1st loop look like?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is because you overwrite elements on each iteration of cycle.
To avoid this you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with list as default value.
Then instead of overwriting you can just append value to the list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for elements in namelist:
    for article in articles:
        list_namecounts = len(re.findall(element,article))
        results[article].append([element, list_namecounts])
```